# ImageView doesn't dispatch TouchEvent

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener, touch-event

I want to change the image (that I get from a web url) in my ImageView when I touch the left or right of the screen. I tried using a TouchListener but I get an error about dispatchTouchEvent.

Using a gallery view is not the solution because I want the images displayed in full screen.

This is the code I use.

```
 public class Prova4Activity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ImageView image;
Bitmap trash = loadImageFromUrl("http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/tt4web/Nazionale/16_9_page-100.6.png");
ImageView imgpag;
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.EDGE_RIGHT){
        trash.recycle();
         trash = null;
         trash = loadImageFromUrl("http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/tt4web/Nazionale/16_9_page-100.6.png");
         image.setImageBitmap(trash);

         }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.EDGE_LEFT){
             trash.recycle();
             trash = null;
             trash = loadImageFromUrl("http://www.televideo.rai.it/televideo/pub/tt4web/Nazionale/16_9_page-100.5.png");
             imgpag.setImageBitmap(trash);

         }
    imgpag.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    return false;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    imgpag = (ImageView)findViewById (R.id.imgpag); 
    imgpag.setImageBitmap(trash);
    imgpag.setOnTouchListener(this);

}
}
```

In logcat I see the following message many times:

```
Key dispatching timed out sending to com.namemyapp Current state {{null Window{439f0e10 com.namemyapp Continuing to wait for key to be dispatched
```

Comment: Can you please include the error you get in your post?

Comment: Yes more information or some code samples would help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Perhaps I could use the method onInterceptTouchEvent to intercept touchevents from my imageview